# grep --exclude-dir not working for multiple directories

Tags: linux, macos

This works fine:

```
↳ grep -Rl "/Logo" . --exclude-dir=node_modules  
./build/static/js/main.a49b832f.chunk.js.map
./src/components/Navbar.tsx
```

However, this does not works

```
↳ grep -Rl "/Logo" . --exclude-dir={node_modules} 
./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/esm/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/index.js
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/3e4a927cd9c9bb86e87f6a71487ba7c6.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/67cfa20e2c31951ea765660d131033ec.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/5fcda2fc94175df2fd227b142700927f.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/a540e181b1381b760e135d69eaa4d001.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/b43b91b3120c2a798f75371de8b76396.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/50c91e99011ef83ed37a132843b1a902.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/7e882ccc48d6ed180a1917590d4ba243.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/187728dc659dfad772f20689545a714a.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/f93a3f858614c6d71e6be2126876b184.json
./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/0676defde7ff6b96560ea8e9fd38d826.json
^C
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I am using M1 MacBook air

Comment: The error is expecting magical properties from the string `{node_modules}`. `{a,b,c}` is magical. `{a..c}` is magical. `{a}` is not.

Comment: Thank you so much!